# Why is my sun (directional light) getting stuck at -90/90 rotation?

Tags: rotation, unreal-engine4

I can't figured out why on Earth my sun is getting gimble locked at 90*.

In .h file

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category="World Environment")
ADirectionalLight *SunLight;
```

in .cpp where I move the sun

```
float p = totalRealTimeSecondsPerGameDay / DeltaTime;
float r = 360 / p;

FRotator newRot;
newRot.Pitch = r;
newRot.Roll = 0.0f;
newRot.Yaw = 0.0f;

SunLight->AddActorLocalRotation(newRot);
```

It works phenomenally.....until it gets to 90* or -90*.

I'm so lost.

Edit: To clarify this is a weird bug, or I'm just missing something, I tried copying my C++ in blueprints to replicate the process exactly and it too stalls at 90 and -90.

I even tried usings Quats as, through my searching, I've seen suggested a lot.

```
FQuat quatRot = FQuat(newRot);
SunLight->AddActorLocalRotation(quatRot, false, 0, ETeleportType::None);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue that only occurs when using relative rotations.

Taking a step back, might I suggest that you use absolute rotations instead of relative? In your current implementation you're going to suffer from cumulative floating point rounding errors; your sun will "drift off" the game time. If you instead use an absolute rotation, you'll guarantee that you stay faithful to the game time, whilst correcting your issue:

```
float gameDaysElapsed = GetWorld()->TimeSeconds / totalRealTimeSecondsPerGameDay;
float alpha;
FMath::Modf(gameDaysElapsed, alpha);

check(FMath::IsWithin(alpha, -SMALL_NUMBER, 1.f + SMALL_NUMBER));    
FRotator rot(alpha * 360.f, 0.f, 0.f);
SunLight->SetActorRotation(rot);
```

As a footnote, this also allows you to apply a function of time in order to change the way your sun behaves in the future, rather than being linear. So it would be easier to make it do things like "pop up" and travel across the centre of the sky slowly, before popping down quickly, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to happen due [Gimbal Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)

You can use AddActorWorldRotation() instead.

```
void ATimeHandler::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
    Sun->AddActorWorldRotation(FRotator(DeltaTime, 0.f, 0.f));
}
```